# Use of the word 'air'

Tags: word-choice

In the following three which one is incorrect?

1. TV channel is relayed.
2. TV channel is aired.
3. TV channel is telecast.

Is a channel 'relayed'or its programs are relayed?

Answer (score 1):

First you need an article:

> *A/The* TV channel is xxx.

Regarding your word choice, dictionary definitions should be helpful.

Regarding the electric signal traveling through the air to your TV, use *broadcast*. *relayed* refers to the signal between transmitters.

*aired* and *telecast* refers to TV programs.